# I want to add a select statement to my superbowl data sheet but how would i add a select where it would show wins per team in SQL?

Tags: sql, case

I am trying to create data for a Superbowl sheet, and I want to create a table in SQL, which shows the number of wins per team with two columns, wins, and team. I need to use CASE. I hope someone will teach me this as I am an amateur and just started coding. **I ASSURE YOU THIS IS NOT SPAM AND IT IS THE LIST OF SUPER BOWLS FROM THE 1ST TO THE 54TH AND I AM NOT A BOT** This is what I have so far:

```
/* Put your data in here and query it! */
CREATE TABLE superbowls(
  Date      TEXT ,
  SB         TEXT,
  Winner     TEXT,
  Winner_Pts INTEGER,
  Loser      TEXT,
  Loser_Pts  INTEGER,
  MVP        TEXT,
  Stadium    TEXT,
  City       TEXT,
  State      TEXT
);

/* https://justpaste.it/99c41 */

select * from superbowls where winner_pts > 10 and loser_pts< 10;
```

Comment: The link is the actual data, but I could not enter into stack overflow, and the code is there to help anybody answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
create table YourNewTable as
select 
  Winner as Team,
  count(*) as Wins
from superbowls
group by Winner
```

Comment: what is the create new table for?

Comment: You said you wanted to create a table in SQL with the result of that query... the `CREATE TABLE` creates the table `YourNewTable` with the output of the query